# Seeking Python support for WMTS 1.0.0

Tags: python, software-recommendations, wmts, ogc, owslib

I am trying to access a WMTS server what only supports version 1.0.0. With OWSlib 0.25 I get:

```
from owslib.wms import WebMapService

base_url= 'https://cyanoalert.brockmann-consult.com/api/latest/'
wms = WebMapService(base_url, version="1.0.0")
```

> NotImplementedError: The WMS version (1.0.0) you requested is not
> implemented. Please use 1.1.1 or 1.3.0.

Is there a Python package that supports the older WMTS 1.0.0?

Comment: You seem to mix WMS and WMTS. The only existing WMTS standard version is 1.0.0 and WMS 1.0.0 is very old and rare.

Comment: That is a WMS you are using not a WMTS, the version numbers are very different

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to access a WM**T**S, use the [`WebMapTileService`](https://geopython.github.io/OWSLib/usage.html#wmts) class, not the `WebMapService` (which is a WMS):

```
from owslib.wmts import WebMapTileService

base_url= 'https://cyanoalert.brockmann-consult.com/api/latest/'
wmts = WebMapTileService(base_url)
```

That particular URL is currently returning a `503 Service Unavailable` error so I can't tell if it's a WMS, a WMTS or something else completely, but the following works correctly:

```
from owslib.wmts import WebMapTileService

base_url= 'https://mrdata.usgs.gov/mapcache/wmts'
wmts = WebMapTileService(base_url)
```